# extracting urls from a page with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this bit of `php` that extracts all urls from a page:

```
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $page, $matches);

$links = ($matches[0]);

foreach($links as $link)
{
  echo $link.'<br />';
}
```

How would I modify it to extract not all links but just the ones that match a certain partial url, in this case: `http://www.site.com/artist/' where the result I am looking for is a list like:

http://www.site.com/artist/Nirvana/

http://www.site.com/artist/Jayz/

And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the delimiters to exclamation points, there was no need for the extra escape characters. The `\s` character class matches whitespace characters like tabs, spaces, and new lines. I'm also making sure we cover both types of quotes (in case the page varies).

```
$regex = '!https?://www.site.com/artist/[^\'"\s]+!i';
preg_match_all($regex, $page, $matches);

$links = ($matches[0]);

foreach($links as $link)
{
  echo $link.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I also came up with this which works: `$regex = '/https?\:\/\/www.site.com\/artist[^\" ]+/i';` but not sure if the difference between the two?

Comment: @ian, the delimiters and you're looking for literal space characters. Mine looks for spaces, tabs, newlines, and both types of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Where are these URLs? Are they on a webpage? Try this:

> http://www.site.com/artist/.*\b

**UPDATE 1:**

If you are using PHP, try this:

```
preg_match_all('%http://www\.site\.com/artist/.*\b%', $html, $urls, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$urls = $urls[0];
```

Comment: also returns: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/PHPCrawl_081/test.php on line 53

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/PHPCrawl_081/test.php on line 60`

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = 'http:\/\/www.site.com\/artist\/[^" ]+\/';
```

Of course, what goes after the `artist` part depends on what is considered acceptable input.

If you are only accepting letters and numbers then just use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: Returns:`Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/PHPCrawl_081/test.php on line 53

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/PHPCrawl_081/test.php on line 60`

Comment: Seems like you forgot your delimiters in your call to `preg_match_all()`. It should work with `preg_match_all ("/{$regex}/", $val, $m))` (notice the delimiters). Alternatively, put the delimiters in the `$regex` declaration like so: `$regex = '/http:\/\/www.site.com\/artist\/[^" ]+\//';`