# extracting urls from page with regex in php

Tags: php, regex

How would I make a `regex` to extract `urls` from a page where I am matching to a center part of a `url`

For example my urls to match would be something like:

`http://m2.imageserver.net/media/thumb/66177422433.jpg`
`http://m4.imageserver.net/media/thumb/21717623342.jpg`
`http://m1.imageserver.net/media/thumb/12327722433.jpg`

And I want to match by just the `imageserver.net/media` section of the url as the sub domain may change.

Comment: are they links or plain text?

Comment: `strpos($haystack, $needle)` seems to be an easier approach

Comment: Better than what? Why do you think there is a browser application?

Comment: @zerkms links in a crawled page.

Comment: Use dom and xpath then `//a/@href[contains(., "imageserver.net/media")]` :-)

Comment: What's the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093233/extracting-urls-from-a-page-with-regex ?

Comment: @zerkms - not sure I tried to use that code and just put in the partial url but no luck. Not good with regex yet and though maybe I needed to change things around when the match does not start at the same place.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor - Could work but I want to quickly extra the full `url` also and multiple iterations of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be `http://[a-zA-Z0-9]+.imageserver.net+[a-zA-Z0-9/]+.jpg`.

**Advice:** Before trying out on code, please check using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com). It's basically a javascript regex tester.

**Update:** Adding a delimiter:

```
$match_pattern = "#http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+.imageserver.net+[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+.jpg#";
preg_match_all($match_pattern,$string_to_be_matched,$url_array);
```

Comment: That gives me a: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /Users/user/Dropbox/localhost/PHPCrawl_081/test.php on line 61
`

Comment: @ian: How about adding a delimiter? Have you made a research on how to work with regexes in php?

Answer (score 0):

I have try this one for you. maybe it can help you though.

```
$text = "http://m2.imageserver.net/media/thumb/66177422433.jpg";

$text = preg_match("/imageserver.net\/media/", $text, $match);

print_r($match);
```

If I totally understand your question this might be the answer.

Comment: And the `$match` array will be a bunch of `'imageserver.net/media'` strings

Comment: yes but if you output the $text it shows 1 or true if there is a match.

Comment: read the question once again - OP needs to extract urls

Answer (score 0):

I don't use regex much but I think this might work.

```
$string = "jjYy5nhttp://m2.imageserver.net/media/thumb/66177422433.jpgru56rtjr";

    $pattern = "/http:\/\/[^0-9a-zA-Z_ -].imageserver.net\/media\/(.*?).jpg/";
    if (@preg_match_all(${pattern}, ${string}, $matches) ) {
       print $matches['0'];
    }
```